# Python: Exporting text list to a text file

Tags: python

I am new to Python and I was wondering how to save this hashed password list (stored in variable *passwords*)

```
['73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc', '2de9210e9173ca4151bb220a2ded6cdb', '8c064f4067cf0c59c68ec281f5786cb2']
```

to a text file in the format:

```
73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc
2de9210e9173ca4151bb220a2ded6cdb
8c064f4067cf0c59c68ec281f5786cb2
```

currently I am able to save it to a text file however it saves as

```
['73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc', '2de9210e9173ca4151bb220a2ded6cdb', '8c064f4067cf0c59c68ec281f5786cb2']
```

current code to save file:

```
f = open( 'hash.txt', 'w' )
f.write(repr(passwords) + '\n' )
f.close()
```

Please help :) Thank you

Reason for wanting to save in text is so I can call that list in a new script to decrypt them however because it saves as a list (and imports as a list) it creates a list in a list and messes up my decryption script.

Edit: Thank you all for the great answers :) its a huge help!

Comment: So your problem is that when you try and import the file another list is being created?

Comment: @Inkblot Yes, so I was thinking by saving it as a different format it may fix my issue with decrypting. When I import the file (in another script) it comes out as:
`["['73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc', '2de9210e9173ca4151bb220a2ded6cdb', '8c064f4067cf0c59c68ec281f5786cb2']\n"]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save it like this:

```
with open('hash.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('\n'.join(passwords))
```

This achieves what you waht to do. (You could avoid the with-statement)

Load it like this:

```
passwords = []
with open('hash.txt', 'r') as f:
    passwords.extend(f.read().split('\n'))
```

To use Python 3, you would have to be careful to convert the bytes to str first...

Greets.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, it must be `passwords.extend()` - not `passwords.append()`.

Comment: When trying to load (I printed password after) and its print like this: `[['73868cb1848a216984dca1b6b0ee37bc', '2de9210e9173ca4151bb220a2ded6cdb', '8c064f4067cf0c59c68ec281f5786cb2']]`

Would you know how to fix this? Thanks again (its a list in a list)

Comment: Sorry nevermind, just seen the latest edit. Thank you :) it now works

Comment: If you extend to a empty list, you can leave it out completely and just assign `passwords = f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: Yes, you are right, but I was not sure, whether he wants to import more files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code :

```
f = open( 'hash.txt', 'w' )
for a in passowrds:
 f.write(a + '\n' ) #you have to pass them as separate variables 
f.close()
```

Whenever you have to take out take out values from a list, you can use the *for loop* Example

```
list = ["cat","dog","lion"]
for animal in list:
   print animal
```

This will print each animal in the list. You can use any other variable name in place of animal.

Comment: why do you use `repr(a)`? - `a` would be sufficient in python2.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `readlines()` to pass the text from the file into the list and use that list like so:

```
passwords = []

with open('hash.txt', 'r') as f:
    passwords = f.readlines()
f.close()
```

If you come across `'\n'`, then just use something like `"".join(passwords)`

Comment: I think the problem is, that the file has the wrong format, because it is written with `repr()`, not that it cannot be read.

Comment: Look at the comments below the OP's question, he stated a different problem or atleast slightly different to the original question

Comment: The problem is, that he saves it in one line, which makes parsing unnecessary complicated. This is the reason, why his script reads it in as `["['...', '...', ...]"]`.
It's easier to save it in multiple lines.

Answer (score 0):

To open:

```
f = open('hash.txt', 'w')
```

To save:

```
f.write(file_path)
```